# Google-test : Comparing file outputted by unit-tested function with reference file

Tags: c++, file, googletest

I am unit-testing a function whose purpose is to store data under a certain format into a file. I want to unit-test this function to make sure that the file it outputs indeed matches a reference file. Is there a way to do that with the google test library directly? Or do I have to implement a function to compare two files myself?

Comment: unit-testing and operating on files, pick one

Comment: @MichałWalenciak so you cannot unit-test a unit of your program whose purpose is to generate a file? Why not?

Comment: Because then there are 2 units: your function and file system, so you have integration test. The only reason for your test to fail should be a bug in your function. No external reasons like disk error etc.
In your case try to refactor your function so it works on ostream or something similar which you can mock.

Comment: @GLorieul Unit tests don't usually mess with the file system, db, etc. Those would be more integration tests. To test if the format is correct, you can make your function output to a stream, and in tests use a stringstream instead of a file stream, and then compare the string created. In short, separate the creation of the data to write from the writing-to-file process.

Comment: MichałWalenciak MikMik all right, got it. Thanks to both!

Comment: [How Do I Unit Test Something That Writes To A File?](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/how-do-i-unit-test-something-that-writes-to-a-file/)